# CPU registers state on the very start of the app. PE executables

Tags: winapi, disassembly, portable-executable, ollydbg

Platform: Windows XP, average PE file
What defines CPU registers initial values on the very start of the application ?
On the screenshot below OllyDbg stopped at the application entry point. But CPU registers already have some values(EDX == KiFastSystemCallReg?), PF/ZF==1, stack is not empty as well(SEH chain?).[image]

Does it mean that something was ran before we got to app entry point ? What is it ?

Comment: While waiting for Raymond Chen to arrive with the (in)formal details, I don't think you can rely on anything except that esp and ebp are set up for immediate use (ebp chains back to the original process startup code within kernel, I believe). Also, the direction flag and floating point rounding word can be assumed to have known, good values, ready to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

offsets pertain to x86 xp sp3 for other os lookup the CONTEXT structure in winnt.h / ntddk.h

ctrl+g ->type ntdll.ZwContinue-> ok->F2-> restart the exe

ollydbg will break at ZwContinue -> alt+f1 to open commandline plugin type 
follow [[esp+4]+b8] -> ok -> f2->f9 you will see a blank stack single step and see who fills the stack now

ZwContinue takes 2 arguments first argument is a pointer to CONTEXT structure whose memeber eip is at 0xb8 from start of Structure this eip will be BaseProcessStartThunk this is the function responsible for filling the initial Structured Exception handler and calling the Module EntryPoint