# load ELF file into memory

Tags: c, assembly, static, arm, elf

I'm trying to put an elf file into memory and then execute it, these are the steps:

1- file to put into memory

```
int main()
{
   printf("Hello world! \n");
   return 0;
}
```

2- Compile it `gcc -o hello hello.c -static`

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8120
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          119864 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000000, Version5 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         4
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         18
  Section header string table index: 17

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00008000 0x00008000 0x16828 0x16828 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x016840 0x0001f840 0x0001f840 0x00250 0x02660 RW  0x1000
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RWE 0
  EXIDX          0x015f40 0x0001df40 0x0001df40 0x008e8 0x008e8 R   0x4
```

3- I write a Loader (compiled for ARM)

```
mmap2(0x8000, 92200, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x8000
mmap2(0x1f000, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x1f000
```

3.1- Then I have copied all the elf bytes into the allocations

3.2- jmp to main function

```
ldr r0, =0x008160
blx r0

.text:00008160 ; int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
.text:00008160                 EXPORT main
.text:00008160 main                                    ; DATA XREF: _start+8o
.text:00008160                                         ; .text:off_8150o
.text:00008160                 STMFD           SP!, {R11,LR}
.text:00008164                 ADD             R11, SP, #4
.text:00008168                 LDR             R3, =(aHelloWorld - 0x8174)
.text:0000816C                 ADD             R3, PC, R3 ; "Hello world! "
.text:00008170                 MOV             R0, R3
.text:00008174                 BLX             puts
.text:00008178                 MOV             R3, #0
.text:0000817C                 MOV             R0, R3
.text:00008180                 LDMFD           SP!, {R11,PC}
.text:00008180 ; End of function main
```

The problem is that every time I get to the line 0x8174, then jump into, after a bit of instructions I always have a SIGSEGV in a random position, more time the crash instruction is => `0x9cc0:   ldr r0, [r0, #4]` with `r0=0x70a34`

```
00008000-0002f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
80000000-80001000 r-xp 00000000 b3:18 129754     /data/local/tmp/main
80001000-8001a000 rwxp 00001000 b3:18 129754     /data/local/tmp/main
becdf000-bed00000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]
```

These are more instructions after the crash:

```
.text:00009CB4 loc_9CB4                                ; CODE XREF: pthread_mutex_lock_impl+18j
.text:00009CB4                 MOV             R3, #0xFFFF0FE0
.text:00009CBC                 BLX             R3
.text:00009CC0                 LDR             R0, [R0,#4]
```

At this location `0x9CB4`, the value of `r0` is `0x1f96c` (it is ok), after the blx the value of `r0` is `0x70a34`

```
(gdb) x/10x 0xffff0fe0
0xffff0fe0: 0xee1d0f70  0xe12fff1e  0xee1d0f70  0x00000000
0xffff0ff0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000005
0xffff1000: Cannot access memory at address 0xffff1000
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should at least resolve all dynamic dependencies before you can pass control to loaded code. Also `main()` is not a real entry point of your ELF. There is so called startup code - its purpose is to initialize C runtime. Actual entry point address placed somewhere at ELF headers.

Comment: The loader of an operating system does quite a lot more before mapping the executable file in memory and jumping there to execute it.

Comment: Well, yeah, where's that `puts` call going to go, exactly? Have you loaded and initialised the C library? Fixed up all the relocations? Loading anything more than a trivial, statically-linked, position-independent binary is going to take rather more than two `mmap`s and a `memcpy`.

Comment: @Serhio yes sorry I missing this point, if I set the entry point ldr r0, =0x008120, this is my output: mmap2(0x8000, 92200, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x8000
mmap2(0x1f000, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x1f000
gettid()                                = 3582
set_tls(0x201a0, 0x40, 0, 0x202a0, 0x201a0) = 0
futex(0x202ec, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL
and wait forever

Comment: @Notlikethat this is the crash line sometimes: => 0x9cc0: ldr r0, [r0, #4], with r0=0x70a34, this is the memory mapped: 00008000-0002f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
80000000-80001000 r-xp 00000000 b3:18 129754     /data/local/tmp/main
80001000-8001a000 rwxp 00001000 b3:18 129754     /data/local/tmp/main
becdf000-bed00000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]

Comment: So? If you dump a couple of ELF sections into memory, ignore the entry point, and blindly jump straight into the middle of one of them, you're pretty much guaranteed to crash somewhere. The nature of _that_ crash isn't at all interesting; would you call an auto electrician to diagnose why your car won't start, if your car was _on fire_?

Comment: @Notlikethat thanks for your response, I agree on the fact of the crash details, then actually I map the two LOAD program header into memory and then I jmp to entry point (I tried also into main function), then what is the correct way for do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm trying to put an elf file into memory and then execute it,

For a fully-statically-linked executable, your steps would work (except you need to jump to `_start` == entry point `0x8120`, *not* `main`).

> Then I have copied all the elf bytes into the allocations

Another possible problem is not paying attention to the `.p_offset`. Your `memcpy`ies should look something like this:

```
unsigned char buf1[0x16828];  // read 0x16828 bytes from start of file
memcpy(0x8000, buf1, 0x16828);

unsigned char buf2[0x250];  // read 0x250 bytes from offset 0x016840 into the file
memcpy(0x0001f840, buf2, 0x250);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a dynamically-linked executable because there's no INTERP program header. If it were dynamically linked that would contain the name of the dynamic loader, and all he have to do load and properly execute that instead. His problem is that he's not using the correct entry point.

Comment: @RossRidge You are correct. He has `-static` on the link line. Sorry I missed that.

Comment: re the previous version of this answer: On a dynamic binary, you could just load the ELF interpreter into memory like the kernel does, and jump to its entry point, right?  If you just want to avoid ever calling execve(), that shouldn't stop you from still using the existing dynamic linker.

Comment: @EmployedRussian thanks for your response, the problem is the offset 0x016840 that I have neglected in the loader. Then if I jump to main 0x008160, not entry point, it work!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you need to use the correct entry point and you need initialize the program's stack (and maybe registers) the same way the OS would. You need to use the correct entry point so that the C runtime library is initialized, otherwise your call to `printf` (or `puts` as the case may be) will almost certainly crash. You need to setup the stack correctly because that's where the C runtime library's initialization code will look for the program's arguments and environment (and maybe other things).

You didn't say what operating system you're using, but if your using Linux you might want to look as an answer to different question given by CesarB [describing the initial state of the stack on ARM Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6002815).