# Access ARGV Arm Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, argv

I'm trying to get the contents of argv and display them.

The program would be called like `./main 5 6 7`.

r0 = argc

r1 = argv[0]

r2 = argv[1]

This program properly gets the number of command line arguments, but it doesn't work the same by using r1 and printing a string. It prints random characters that vary based on the number of args.

```
.text
.global main
.extern printf
main:
        push {ip, lr}
        mov r1, r0
        ldr r0, =string
        bl printf
        pop {ip, pc}

.data
string: .asciz "Argc: %d\n"
```

Argv:

```
.text
.global main
.extern printf
main:
        push {ip, lr}
        mov r1, r2
        ldr r0, =string
        bl printf
        pop {ip, pc}

.data
string: .asciz "Argv: %s\n"
```

Comment: Why do you think `argv[0]` is in `r1` and `argv[1]` is in `r2`?  I'm like 95% sure that that's wrong.

Comment: @zwol Function arguments are passed in r0, r1, etc.

Comment: Only up to some limit, and more importantly, `argv[0]`, `argv[1]`, etc should not be passed as separate arguments.  Did you try the thing in my answer?

Comment: @zwol I did not get the chance but rethinking it, all of argv should be in r1 and offsets could be used to step through it.

Comment: most likely that r1 is a pointer to a pointer **argv.  or *argv[] or argv[][] however you look at it is just a pointer not an element, so it is likely a pointer to an array of pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`argv` is an array, passed to `main` as a single argument, not a sequence of arguments.  `argv[0]` in C therefore translates to `[r1]` in ARM assembly, `argv[1]` to `[r1,4]`, `argv[2]` to `[r1,8]`, and so on.  The offset ticks up by four bytes per array element because `argv` is an array of pointers, and this is plain ARM (not AArch64), so pointers are 32 bits wide, which is 4 bytes.

If you change

```
    mov r1, r2
```

to

```
    ldr r1, [r1, 4]
```

your program should work correctly.

Note that you should also clear `r0` after the call to `printf`, so that `main` returns zero, not garbage.

You might find the [ARM Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf) helpful.

Comment: yes, if you make a test function and disassemble it that is exactly where argv[1] lives.  r1 is an address to an array of pointers r1+0 is argv[0], r1+4 is argv[1] and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some disassembled ARM code that I'm currently looking at.  I was just trying to figure out the getopt usage.

```
; int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
EXPORT main
main

var_140= -0x140
var_13C= -0x13C
var_138= -0x138
var_130= -0x130
var_32= -0x32
var_30= -0x30
var_2C= -0x2C

STMFD           SP!, {R4-R11,LR}
SUB             SP, SP, #0x11C
MOV             R7, R0  ; R0 contains the argc.  See below
MOV             R6, R1  ; R1 contains the pointer to argv[]
MOV             R3, #0x1434B4
MOV             R5, #0

...some code in between...

MOV             R10, R5
MOV             R4, #aVvk ; "Vvk:" ; setting the shortopts below
ADD             R8, SP, #0x140+var_130
MOV             R9, #optarg ; EXPORT location for optarg
MOV             R11, R5
MOV             R5, #0x1434B4
B               loc_1026F4

loc_1026F4              ; getopt loop starts here
MOV             R0, R7  ; argc
MOV             R1, R6  ; argv
MOV             R2, R4  ; shortopts
BL              getopt  ; call getopt, passing R0, R1, and R2
CMN             R0, #1
BNE             loc_102684

...do the option checks and loop until done...
```

This looks like it supports the answer from @zwol.
Not sure what happens if we have more arguments than can fit in R1 though.  Does it just start using R2?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "more arguments than can fit in R1".  If you are on a system that supports the third `envp` argument to `main`, that will be in R2, but you only need one pointer to point to an array of arbitrary length.

Comment: You might find the [ARM Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf) helpful.

Comment: @zwol 's first comment hits the nail on the head. Argv can have an arbitrary length. Some more on arguments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1803693/3610102).