# GDB Continues Execution Unexpectedly After Linked Branch (ARM Assembly)

Tags: assembly, arm, gdb, gnu-arm

I have a simple ARM Assembly program (below) with a linked branch to a function, which pushes a register onto the stack and branches back to the return address in `lr`.

main.S:

```
.global _start

.section .text
_start:
    mov     r0, #2      // garbage instructions to show that single step works properly with mov
    mov     r1, #2
    mov     r2, #2
    bl      subr

    mov     r7, #0x1
    mov     r0, #0
    swi     0

subr:
    mov     r0, #1
    push    {r0}
    bx      lr
```

When I debug the program with GDB and use `n` to step over the `bl subr` instruction, it continues to the next breakpoint instead of single stepping (GIF 1 below). When I step into `subr` and then single step over `bx lr`, it single steps to the next instruction normally (GIF 2 below). I realized the problem is because of the `push {r0}` instruction in `subr`. If it is removed, the linked branch instruction behaves as normal.

The address in `lr` is `0x10064`, which matches the address of the next instruction after the branch (line 10):

```
(gdb) i r lr
lr             0x10064  65636
(gdb) i line 10
Line 10 of "main.S" starts at address 0x10064 <_start+16> and ends at 0x10068 <_start+20>.
```

Step Over GIF of GDB (not working as expected):

[image: Step Over GIF Link]

Step Into (correct):

[image: Step Into GIF Link]

I am using GDB 7.7.1 on Raspbian Jessie 2017 (QEMU Emulation, stablest OS I could get working) on architecture ARMv6l.

**The question:** In a real project (I am currently working on one), how can I avoid having to single step through a subroutine while still placing the return value on the stack somehow (If I am doing things completely wrong, please tell me)? Why is this happening with the `push` instruction?

Comment: Excuse me for asking but is there markdown code snippet syntax highlighting for assembly languages?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  There are many assembly languages and each would need it's own highlighting, so it would be obnoxiously hard to do so without knowing exactly what assembly language is used.

Comment: as pointed out in an/the answer below imbalance is not a good thing,  why try to use the stack to return instead of a normal register return?   it will create problems in real world software.  if you do a pop before the lr as an experiment what happens?  debuggers create as many problems as they solve, so the bigger question is why using/needing a debugger (decades of bare metal embedded work and have had zero use for one).  if you single step and not step over through this whole sequence does it hit each instruction?

Comment: @old_timer am I correct in interpreting that register returns should be used in most scenarios? (also, very good point about debuggers! thank you)

Comment: ymmv on debuggers.  if you look at the calling conventions used by compilers when you have enough registers is to use registers for some number of caller parameters and return.  If you use the stack for calling/returning then you dont push or pop you reference backward, look at for example x86 in the old days.  you would put your return value in stack pointer plus some offset to get you to the right place then the caller would pop it if you will.

Comment: for example when called the stack pointer would point at the last valid thing. you might have a stack frame that saves the frame pointer and say the link register for a return, so you have added 8 more.  and the caller may be expecting you to save your return value at that last valid location when called so you would write your return value to [sp+8]  or as you often see, the frame pointer is then set to the stack pointer and then the stack pointer can be adjusted further for this function and that would then be [fp+8] and you dont need to worry about what the function does to the stack.

Comment: being assembly you can do whatever you want though. but that does not mean that debuggers will be have how you want. If as proposed the debugger is detecting the stack imbalance and not simply a  branch to link register (note that it is not uncommon in arm to "return" by branching to a register other than the link register and or popping the return address into the program counter, so a debugger has to try to be clever about how to deal with stepping over a function call).

Comment: the debugger at best is going to try to tune for the majority of the use cases which means compiled code (and if needed add to that by a commonly used toolchain/language so gnu and C for example, arm tools and C, etc) and not when we have fun with assembly language and do perfectly valid things but the tools cant read our minds when trying to draw a circle around the high level human concept of a function, which the hardware has zero notion of.

Comment: so the suggestion is and I have not caught up on the whole of this question/page, if you behave like a compiler and use compiler like calling conventions does the debugger behave in a way that you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unbalancing the stack, so it seems that GDB assumes that the function is recursive or otherwise still active, and so doesn't stop upon return to main (since the stack is unbalanced).  GDB is waiting for the stack to return to normal (for `_start`) ***and*** the pc to return to that "next" instruction location, both together, in order to break at the next logical line (methinks, at least).

Unbalancing the stack is not good and could very well upset not just the debugger, but other functions, say, if such function made any use of the stack before & then after making a call to a function that unbalances the stack, such as saving its own return address on the stack to use later.

For example, try writing that same code with `_start` calling a `main`, then that `main` calling `subr`.  That just won't work b/c `main` will have to push its own return address (i.e. to `_start`) before calling `subr` and then pop it after in order to return back to `_start`, but it won't get it right since the stack has been unbalanced by `subr`.

Comment: before even this issue where is the stack pointer being initialized? I am not seeing it is there a bootstrap that everyone but me assumes is there?  A test for this imbalance would be to push then pop then return and see how the debugger behaves.  would be disturbing IMO if the debugger is doing this but at the same time would not surprise me if that is what the debugger is doing.  debuggers create as many problems as they solve.

Comment: @old_timer, yes, very good point.

Comment: @old_timer: Looks to me like this is a user-space process running under Linux (Raspbian), with R7=1 / `swi` being an `exit` system-call.   Thus the stack pointer is initialized by the kernel before entry to user-space, so it's pointing at `argc` as per the System V ABI.  In a mapping that can grow downwards with the usual magic for the main-thread's stack.  ([Initial state of program registers and stack on Linux ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1802783))